# React native navigation custom tabbar icon

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation

Is this possible to have custom component ( Button or what ever ) instead of simple icon in tab bar?

I need to set my tab bar icon dynamically like this

```
this.props.navigator.setTabButton({
          tabIndex: 0,
          icon: <Icon name="heart" size={28} />  <--- not appear    
        });
```

OR we can use only icons? Any solutions?

Comment: hey, did you find any solution for this issue?

Comment: @Rawan, u can't do it like this 

All what u can is - set icon on router mounting

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. I am sharing my solution as code below:

```js
const renderNav = (routeName, focused) => {
    return (
        <View style={{
            flex: 1,
            width: 90,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            borderTopColor: StylesGeneric.COLORS.primary,
            borderTopWidth: focused ? 4 : 0,
        }}>
            <Text
                style={[StylesGeneric.STYLES.footerText]}>
                {routeName}
            </Text>
        </View>
    );
};

const customTabs = ({navigation}) => ({
    tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => {
        const {routeName} = navigation.state;
        if (routeName === 'Home') {
            return renderNav('Home', focused);
        } else if (routeName === 'Profile') {
            return renderNav('Profile', focused);
        } else if (routeName === 'ProfileOther') {
            return renderNav('ProfileOther', focused);
        }
    },
});

const nav = createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        Home: {
            screen: Home,
        },
        Profile: {
            screen: Profile,
        },
        ProfileOther: {
            screen: ProfileOther,
        },
    },
    {
        defaultNavigationOptions: customTabs,
        animationEnabled: true,
        swipeEnabled: true,
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
        initialRouteName: 'Home',
        tabBarOptions: {
            showLabel: false,
            style: {
                borderTopColor: 'transparent',
                backgroundColor: StylesGeneric.COLORS.white,
                height: StylesGeneric.FOOTER_HEIGHT,
            },
        },
    },
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(nav);
```

Comment: Thanks for trying! Unfortunately your code is for React Navigation, but i've asked about React Native Navigation

Comment: @АндрейГузюк As I use this library for React Native projects, I didn't look exact library name. Sorry for the misunderstanding.